# Upgrade/Change the OS version of the VM instance in the gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using `Google-Cloud-Platform` I want to update the os version of my VM instance.
I am using `ubuntu-18.4LTS` and want to upgrade it to the `ubunut-20.04LTS` with all the data.
I got one suggestion in which I ask I can create a whole new VM instance with the new OS that I want but in that case, I will lose the data.
Another Way that I come into my knowledge is using the snapshot.

1. Create a snapshot from the disk.
2. Create a new instance with the new OS version.
3. Add your old disk to your new instance.

But still, after doing this I didn't get any luck I got the new version but not the data of the old machine.

So is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I can't use comment due to insufficient points.

Is there a reason you don't want to use command line to upgrade?

Does this link https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today help?

And this https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-lts-using-command-line/

Comment: Since Google Cloud does not offer features to upgrade operating systems in place, this is the only viable option (answer).